# How is this statement true in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

This is from a program I wrote and I'm at a loss as to why this is true.

```
user=> (defn isClose [t1] (fn [t2] (and (<= (- t1 t2) 20)) (<= (- t2 t1) 20)))
#'user/isClose
user=> ((isClose 50) 10)
true
```

Doesn't this reduce to this?

```
user=> (and (<= 40 20) (<= -40 20))                                            
false
```

Comment: https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace is a good place to start re: solving this kind of thing yourself.

Comment: `isClose` doesn't look like an idiomatic name to me. Functions that return closures like this I often name starting with `make-...` to indicate to the caller that the return value is itself a function that needs to be called. A predicate called `is-close?` would itself just be a function that tests if it's close. hth, interesting question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the parentheses wrong. Let's add some newlines:

```
(defn isClose [t1] 
  (fn [t2] 
    (and (<= (- t1 t2) 20)) 
    (<= (- t2 t1) 20)))
```

Observe that the function body has two expressions, not one: an `and` with a single argument, followed by an unrelated `<=` call. When a function body has multiple expressions, the final expression is returned, after evaluating all earlier expressions for side effects and then discarding them. What you meant to write was

```
(defn is-close [t1] 
  (fn [t2] 
    (and (<= (- t1 t2) 20)
         (<= (- t2 t1) 20))))
```

which indeed behaves as you expected. Note that I have also amended the function name to typical Clojure naming conventions. Of course this makes no semantic difference. It would be even more typical to name it `close?`.

Balancing parentheses by hand is tricky: when I was reading your function, it looked fine. Only after expanding it to multiple lines, and letting a decent editor auto-indent so the layout matches the semantics, was the problem obvious. I suggest using a lisp-aware editor, and inserting newlines for clarity; you should find the indentation helpful.

Comment: And for further simplification, just write `(<=  (abs (- t1 t2))  20)`

Comment: I actually did try that but I was in a version that was too early and it didn't have it. :(